# Spark Structured Streaming windowing and grouping operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have successfully done grouping operations on my streaming data frame to calculate average number of passengers in the car per trip.

```
val carSchema =
    new StructType()
    .add("trackId", StringType)
    .add("carId", StringType)
    .add("peopleCount", StringType)
    .add("time", StringType)
```

There are several car racing tracks in this problem (3 in my case). Each of them has their own unique "trackId". Within these tracks, there might be multiple cars driving, each car has a separate "carId". We are also keeping track of how many people are in the car using "peopleCount". Field "time" corresponds to the starting time of the race of a given car.

Because we want to calculate the average number of people in cars, we are transforming "peopleCount" from string to int:

```
val dataFrame = 
    inputStream.selectExpr("CAST (content AS STRING) AS JSON")
    .select(from_json($"json", schema = carSchema)
    .as("carData"))
    .select("carData.*")
    .withColumn("peopleCount", toInt($"peopleCount"))

dataFrame.printSchema
root
 |-- trackId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- carId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- peopleCount: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
```

For reference, data looks like this:

```
|trackId                             |carId                               |peopleCount |time                        |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|a85f22a3-5f57-4bde-ad00-5eeb303a9859|2           |2017-12-20T23:04:14.7900000Z|
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|a85f22a3-5f57-4bde-ad00-5eeb303a9859|1           |2017-12-20T23:23:34.5510000Z|
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|984ec5d7-f4a6-422b-aeb6-d130efaf0001|2           |2017-12-20T19:27:57.7710000Z|
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|984ec5d7-f4a6-422b-aeb6-d130efaf0001|3           |2017-12-19T19:29:32.9790000Z|
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|984ec5d7-f4a6-422b-aeb6-d130efaf0001|4           |2017-12-19T19:31:12.6600000Z|
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|984ec5d7-f4a6-422b-aeb6-d130efaf0001|1           |2017-12-19T19:32:52.7190000Z|
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|a85f22a3-5f57-4bde-ad00-5eeb303a9859|2           |2017-12-19T23:45:06.4140000Z|
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|a85f22a3-5f57-4bde-ad00-5eeb303a9859|3           |2017-12-20T21:09:03.7440000Z|
|52f4c09c-7b9d-45d9-96ac-e0fe49458962|2f16b0f9-164c-4e3d-a5c9-f672bcf87197|3           |2017-12-19T21:25:06.2340000Z|
|52f4c09c-7b9d-45d9-96ac-e0fe49458962|2f16b0f9-164c-4e3d-a5c9-f672bcf87197|3           |2017-12-20T18:10:03.6540000Z|
<...more data...>
```

Now, because we want to find out average number of people in cars per track:

```
val avgPeopleInCars = dataFrame.groupBy("trackId").avg("peopleCount")
```

This returns correct averages. There are 3 racing tracks and I am receiving 3 lines returned with averages on amount of people in cars for each of those three racing tracks:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|trackId                             |avg(peopleCount)  |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|3.5               |
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|2.0               |
|52f4c09c-7b9d-45d9-96ac-e0fe49458962|1.0               |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|trackId                             |avg(peopleCount)  |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.5               |
|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|2.2               |
|52f4c09c-7b9d-45d9-96ac-e0fe49458962|3.0               |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Currently, I am trying to understand how to shape the output to use windowing with window size 3 minutes and sliding interval of 1 minute. And still do the same calculation: average number of people in a car per trip. My initial attempt was:

```
val windowedData = 
    dataFrame
    .groupBy(window($"time", "3 minutes", "1 minute"), $"trackId")
    .avg("peopleCount")

windowedData.printSchema
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- trackId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(peopleCount): double (nullable = true)
```

However, this doesn't look right. I would like to receive the same type of output as from the previous step - each window output data set should include 3 rows, one per racing track.

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|window                                       |trackId                             |avg(peopleCount)  |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|[2017-12-18 23:02:00.0,2017-12-18 23:05:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
|[2017-12-18 23:03:00.0,2017-12-18 23:06:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
|[2017-12-18 23:04:00.0,2017-12-18 23:07:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|window                                       |trackId                             |avg(peopleCount)  |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|[2017-12-18 23:02:00.0,2017-12-18 23:05:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
|[2017-12-18 23:03:00.0,2017-12-18 23:06:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
|[2017-12-18 23:04:00.0,2017-12-18 23:07:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|1.0               |
|[2017-12-21 18:55:00.0,2017-12-21 18:58:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|2.0               |
|[2017-12-21 18:56:00.0,2017-12-21 18:59:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|2.0               |
|[2017-12-21 18:57:00.0,2017-12-21 19:00:00.0]|4ccfeb47-c76f-43f4-87bd-7a5777f78e7a|2.0               |
|[2017-12-21 18:59:00.0,2017-12-21 19:02:00.0]|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|3.0               |
|[2017-12-21 19:00:00.0,2017-12-21 19:03:00.0]|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|2.0               |
|[2017-12-21 19:01:00.0,2017-12-21 19:04:00.0]|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|2.0               |
|[2017-12-21 19:02:00.0,2017-12-21 19:05:00.0]|f261a42d-a7ac-4a2d-81b4-c5c7189a2b66|2.5               |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thanks so much for looking at it. I have updated the question. It looks like the windowing operation works fine, however there's something wrong with how the query groups data. What I'd like to have is 3 entries per time window, corresponding to each of the 3 racing tracks, with average count of people in cars. I am already doing "grouping" by "trackId", however it still returns multiple entries.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you will see that it is not returning multiple entries, but it gives you one entry per "window".

I am not an expert in windowing, but I guess if you put an appropriate watermark you will only have latest window.